# What type of signal conditioning is needed for this type of sensor?

Tags: sensor, datasheet, piezoelectricity

Regarding a piezo sensor like [this one](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/DFRobot%20PDFs/SEN0294_Web.pdf), if I want to read the output by an ADC does it require a buffer, a instrumentation amplifier or a type of interface?

I don't know the output impedance of it and cannot figure put how to condition before I hook it up to an ADC.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a piezo sensor, it is a thin-film sensor. It is basically a pressure-sensitive resistor, so you just need to put it in a voltage divider with another resistor and measure the resulting voltage with your ADC. The pressure/resistance curve on page 2 of the data sheet should give you an idea of what value you need for the fixed resistor in the voltage divider.

Answer (score 0):

Comined with Elliot's information, the Specifications on the last page state:

- Open resistance is >10MΩ
- With a trigger force of 20g, the resistance is about 200kΩ
- Max 6kg can be applied, and using the formula shown in the chart, this will result in a resistance of about:

$$y=153.18x^{-0.699}$$
$$y=153.18 \cdot 6000\text{g}^{-0.699}$$
$$y=153.18 \cdot 0.002285979$$
$$y=0.350166$$

Now this is not Ohms, this is the vertical scale of the chart.  If the data is to be believed, a vertical value of near 7 equates to 20g actuation, so about 200kΩ.  To scale this y value to Ohms then (assuming the vertical scale is linear):

$$\frac{200\text{k}}{7} = 28,571.42857 \text{Ohms/tick}$$
$$28,571.42857 \cdot 0.350166 = 10,004.74 \Omega$$

So the sensor is essentially "open" with less than 20g on it, and logarithmic from 20g to 6000g, with the lowest possible resistance being about 10kΩ.